# Connection Manager Expression v Script Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Say I have a dynamic connection manager as desctibed in this webpage: http://sql-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/dynamic-database-connection-using-ssis.html

What is the difference between setting the connection string property as a connection manager expression and setting the connection string property in a Script Task (like in the link).  Are there any pros and cons of each approach?

I have spent a while this morning Googling but I am yet to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've applied in SSIS packages both using a connection string in an expression and in C# Script Tasks as presented in the link you provided.  Although most of the time it was in the expressions.  There are several pros and cons to both.

**Setting up connection string property in Script Task**

Pros:

- Can be set up to be more customized to handle work not supported by other tasks.  (As an example, I had to apply this approach once for importing records from Microsoft Project files.  Since this was not one of the source types typically supported, I had to program this from scratch.)
- Much of the work can be performed in a single task.

Cons:

- Cannot be easily shared with other tasks outside of the script task, even if it its scope is at the package level.
- More difficult for others to troubleshoot should there be a problem at 2:00 AM and you, as the developer, are on vacation.  So be sure to document your code thoroughly.

**Setting Connection string in the expression of a connection manager**

Pros:

- Much easier to set up and troubleshoot.
- More dynamic in its application between different tasks.  For example, this is the best approach for applying in a ForEach loop when a source must be read with each pass of the loop.
- More universally applied and follows a standard format in its application.

Con:

- Not easily applied in more customized requirements.

I usually apply the connection string in an expression.  It is easier to set up and very few people in my office know C#.  You should apply the more customized approach only when it is necessary on a case-by-base basis.

Hope this helps.  I may come back to this with more pros and cons as I think of them.  Good question though.